# How to generate a custom possible combination between two pairs of coordinates?

Tags: python

I have the following list 
`[[(8.048829615534657, 19.980817657439072), (6.524270847706501, 19.57231336678573), (6.932775138359842, 18.047754598957575)]]` which they are the coordinate points. 
So, I would like to convert it to:

```
[[(8.048829615534657, 19.980817657439072), (6.524270847706501, 19.57231336678573)]

 [(6.524270847706501, 19.57231336678573), (6.932775138359842, 18.047754598957575)]]
```

The end point of the first sublist is the starting point of the second sublist. 
Thank you

Comment: Could you please simplify the values in your data to make it easier to read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one simple way of doing it:

```
initial = [[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5,6)]]

restult = [initial[0][:2],initial[0][1:]]
```

It gives the following result:

```
[[(1, 2), (3, 4)], 
[(3, 4), (5, 6)]]
```

ps. Not quite sure why you use dubble brackets, the [0] is just there to ignore the first bracket.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a utility `pairs` function to create pair from list:

```
def pairs(ps):
    for i in range(1, len(ps)):
        yield (ps[i - 1], ps[i])


coords = [
    [
        (8.048829615534657, 19.980817657439072),
        (6.524270847706501, 19.57231336678573),
        (6.932775138359842, 18.047754598957575),
    ]
]

list(map(list, pairs(coords[0])))  # im using first ele, as its list of list
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can do it is using `zip`

```
x = data[0]
[[i, j] for i, j in zip(x[:-1], x[1:])]
```